# Accessing post data before functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am updating my custom Wordpress theme, but as it is rather time consuming process I would like to launch one section at a time. 
In other words there would be several versions of a theme for different parts of the website.
To keep things tidy I would like to keep them in separate folders, with all the assets such as js, images, css.

I managed to rewrite template hierarchy using conditional tags but got stuck on functions.php

I was trying to use custom filed (post meta) to switch between several functions.php files but unfortunately $post is not available there so I am unable to use get_post_meta().

I could only find a trace of a solution with custom db queries, $wpdb etc. but can't really figure it out.

Is there any fairly simple solution to hook-up into post data (wp_query) before functions.php is loaded? Or to somehow differently modify where the functions are loaded from?

To illustrate what I'm writing about I pasted my main index.php

```html
<?
get_header();

/*
 * Get theme version according to the custom field 'section'
 */
 
if( function_exists ( 'theme_version' ) ){
 $theme = theme_version( @get_the_ID() );
} else {
 $theme = 'v2';
}

include_once( 'theme/'. $theme .'/TEMPLATE_BUILDER.php' );


get_footer();

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Done some more digging and it seems that `add_action('template_redirect', function(){ ... ` in my main _functions.php_ does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully found a right answer (after couple of hours of research, trial and error)

I placed the below code in main (wp-native) functions.php
in attempt to keep the code and file structure tidy, works as a charm.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function(){

    // parse_url tidies-up the uri
    $section = get_post_meta( url_to_postid( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH ) ),'section', true);
    if ( !empty( $section )){

        // assign sections to the theme versions below
        $theme_version = array(

            'v3' => array(
                'Sixth Form',
                [ ... ]
            ),

            'v3.1' => array(
                'Contact',
                [ ... ]
            )

        );
        foreach($theme_version as $key => $value) { if(in_array( $section, $value )) $theme = $key; }   
    }
    if( empty($theme) ) $theme = 'v2';   // default theme version

    require_once(  'theme/' . $theme . '/functions.php' );

    $GLOBALS['theme-ver'] = $theme; // set the global to use in index.php (and somewhere else perhaps)

});
```

The code is not complete yet – needs some conditional clauses as the functions.php is sometimes called multiple times within the loop (especially with custom wp_query)

Perhaps someone will find the above useful. By the way it's quite surprising that WP doesn't natively support some kind of 'theme version control' – I can see strong benefits of not having to upgrade the whole website at once for instance to e. g. resp.